# How to access directory with full file path?

Tags: java, file

So, I'm writing a program that needs to iterate through all files in a directory and here is what I currently have.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

      VotingData v = new VotingData();

      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.print("Please input a directory.");
      String input = in.next();

      File dir = new File(input);
      File[] directoryListing = dir.listFiles();

      if (directoryListing != null) {
         for (File child : directoryListing) {
            v.merge(RecordReader.readRecord(child.toString()));
         }
      } 

      else {
       // do nothing right now.  
      }

      String[] sub1 = {"Montgomery","Miami"};
      TextualRepresentation.toString(v.getAllResults());
      TextualRepresentation.toString(v.getCountyResults("Montgomery"));
      TextualRepresentation.toString(v.getCountyResults("Miami"));
      TextualRepresentation.toString(v.getCountyResults("Butler"));
      TextualRepresentation.toString(v.getSubsetResults(sub1));

   }

}
```

The filepath of the project is C:\Users\Jarrett Willoughby\Documents\School\CSE201\Project Stuff.

The input I'm trying is "C:\Users\Jarrett Willoughby\Documents\School\CSE201\Project Stuff\TestFiles" , but it doesn't seem to work. However, when input is just "TestFiles" it does. I want to be able to access directories in different folders, but for some reason the long method isn't working.

Edit: I don't know what the error is. All I know is when I put "TestFiles" into the Scanner it works fine and when I try the full file path it doesn't crash, but it doesn't yield the results I want.

Comment: "it doesn't seem to work" isn't an accurate description of your problem, and your source code doesn't show how you provide the filepath to your code - and this is probably where your problem is. So please edit your question with the error message and that part of your source code. My first guess that you are providing the path as a String in Java - in that case you need to double all backslashes (`C:\\Users\\Jarret ...` etc.)  because the backslash is a special escape character in a Java string.

Comment: I tried double backslashes and it doesn't seem to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Scanner#next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) reads white-space delimited (by default) string tokens.

Your input:

```
C:\Users\Jarrett Willoughby\Documents\School\CSE201\Project Stuff\TestFiles
```

Contains spaces, so `next()` just reads "C:\Users\Jarrett".

You can use [`Scanner#nextLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) instead.

In the future, to debug on your own, either step through in a debugger to see what values variables have, or add print-outs to verify, e.g. this would have led you to a solution quickly:

```
System.out.println("input was " + input);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Much appreciated.